# Android layout:weightsum

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I want to make like this layout in android:

[image: sample layout]

Main view is scrollview and I dynamically added image buttons to the view with this pattern. I should handle it from code. The number of this buttons change according to size of data.In order to make this pattern I use %3 == in my code. Like this

```
mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size ; i++){
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
        if(i % 3 == 2){
            imageButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.2f));
            imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }else{
            if(i%3 == 1){
                imageButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.1f));
                imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }else{
                imageButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.1f));
                imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

        }
        mainLayout.addView(imageButton);
    }
```

I make my LinearLayout weightsum 0.2 from XML. But its not work. All image buttons that I add to view cover whole line. How can I solve this problem? Is Weightsum is a good solution for such a situation?

Comment: You misunderstand **weights**. `weightSum` is **optional**. Only **layuot_weight** is needed. and the weighted dimension MUST BE set to **0dp**. Other than this... WHY not doing it in **xml**? it's faster, easier and it works as well.

Comment: I dont know how to increase the item number according to data from XML thats why I use this way. It seems more easier for me.

Comment: Instead of using a ScrollView with Items added on the fly, you could use a ListView (which is scrollable). Depending if the row is even or odd, give it a different row layout (this is done in the custom Adapter). EASY.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one

Comment: How can solve my problem if the data size is 2 ? row layout is not fit the number of data

Comment: If you only have 2 data, then use the even layout.